# Is there a simple way to convert lambda into a full expression in Kotlin with Android Studio 3.5.1?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

The code in *popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener* is lambda expression, the function of the code is to show a popup menu.

It's hard to understand lambda expression sometimes.

Is there a simple way to convert a lambda into a full expression ? Is there some utilities to do that?

**Code**

```
 private fun showPopup(v: View, mContext: Context) {
        val popup = PopupMenu(mContext, v)
        popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup_more)

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
             when (it.itemId) {
                   R.id.MenuMoreAbout->{
                    requireActivity().openActivity<UIAbout>()
                   }
             }
            true  // Why do I need add 'true'
        }
        popup.show()
    }
```

Comment: Lambdas are already simplified, what do you mean by "full expression"?

Comment: Thanks! In order to understand the code, I hope to use a normal code instead of Lambdas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to convert a lambda into a full expression ?

Yes there is! First position the cursor on the first curly brace

```
                     Position your cursor at this character
                                 |
                                 v

popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
    when (it.itemId) {
        R.id.MenuMoreAbout->{
            requireActivity().openActivity<UIAbout>()
        }
    }
    true  // Why do I need add 'true'
}
```

then type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for Mac) to bring up the *Quick Fix* menu. Select **Convert to anonymous function**. That will turn the code into the following:

```
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(fun(it: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (it.itemId) {
        R.id.MenuMoreAbout -> {
            requireActivity().openActivity<UIAbout>()
        }
    }
    return true
})
```

which is clearer for someone that is new to Kotlin syntax.

As can be seen, your `true` expression was the return value of the lambda. In Kotlin, the return value of a lambda is the value of the last expression in the lambda. If you prefer, you can make this explicit by replacing

```
true  // Why do I need add 'true'
```

with

```
return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
```

in your original code. See official docs for [Return at Labels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) for more information.

The reason a `Boolean` has to be returned is because the lambda is for the following Java interface which is the type of the argument to `setOnMenuItemClickListener(OnMenuItemClickListener)`

```
    public interface OnMenuItemClickListener {
        boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item);
    }
```

As you can see, `onMenuItemClick(MenuItem)` returns a `boolean` (which is converted to `Boolean` in Kotlin). So the lambda must also return a `Boolean`.